# intersectionObserver API: If the element is outside of the viewport

Tags: javascript

I wrote the bellow code which is adding some inline styling to an element once the element is out of the viewport.

```
const myDiv = document.querySelector('.my-div')

const obr = new IntersectionObserver(function(entries) {
    if (entries[0].intersectionRatio <= 0) {
    myDiv.style.top = '100px';
  }
});

obr.observe(myDiv);
```

The above code works fine.

But now I need to add the inline styling when only 100px of the element's height is still in the viewport. In other words the styling shouldn't get added once the element is entirely outside of the viewport but it should be added when most part of it is outside of the viewport and 100px of its height is still in the viewport.

How can I change the above code to achieve that?
I think I need to set **rootMargin** to 100px, but not sure how to implement it into my code.

I tried this:

```
const observer = new IntersectionObserver({ rootMargin: '100px' }, entries => {...
```

But then I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'IntersectionObserver': parameter 1 is not of type 'Function'.
```

Comment: You can set `thresholds` covered in the docs: [How intersection is calculated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API#how_intersection_is_calculated). For specific help you'll need to include your HTML, but basically just calculate the ratio of `100px/entry.height`.

Comment: Thanks. I think what I need here is setting a rootMargin of 100px but not sure how to implement it into my code.

Comment: You simply pass it in the `options` parameter, which is the **second** parameter `new IntersectionObserver(entries => {..}, { rootMargin: '100px' })` (this adds `100px` to all sides of the container. It mirrors the CSS margin syntax)

Comment: I'm sure I tried that and it didn't work. But now it's working. Thanks for your help.